# Cannot compile MFRC522 minimal I2C example

Tags: esp32, rfid

On ESP32 I'm trying to build the [Minimal I2C](https://github.com/MakerSpaceLeiden/rfid/blob/master/examples/Minimal-I2C/Minimal-I2C.ino) example of the [MFRC522 library](https://github.com/makerspaceleiden/rfid):
But I get errors on the first declarations:

```
TwoWire i2cBus = TwoWire(0);
MFRC522_I2C dev = MFRC522_I2C(RST_PIN, 0x28, i2cBus);
MFRC522 mfrc522 = MFRC522(dev); // <--- error
```

Here the build output:

```
src/rfid.cpp:6:30: error: no matching function for call to 'MFRC522::MFRC522(MFRC522_I2C&)'
 MFRC522 mfrc522 = MFRC522(dev);
                              ^
In file included from include/rfid.h:5,
                 from src/rfid.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:348:2: note: candidate: 'MFRC522::MFRC522(byte, byte)'
  MFRC522(byte chipSelectPin, byte resetPowerDownPin);
  ^~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:348:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 1 provided
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:347:2: note: candidate: 'MFRC522::MFRC522(byte)'
  MFRC522(byte resetPowerDownPin);
  ^~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:347:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MFRC522_I2C' to 'byte' {aka 'unsigned char'}
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:346:2: note: candidate: 'MFRC522::MFRC522()'
  MFRC522() DEPRECATED_MSG("use MFRC522(MFRC522_BUS_DEVICE bus_device)");
  ^~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:346:2: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:343:2: note: candidate: 'MFRC522::MFRC522(MFRC522_BUS_DEVICE*)'
  MFRC522(MFRC522_BUS_DEVICE * dev);
  ^~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:343:2: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MFRC522_I2C' to 'MFRC522_BUS_DEVICE*'
In file included from include/rfid.h:5,
                 from src/rfid.cpp:1:
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:152:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr MFRC522::MFRC522(const MFRC522&)'
 class MFRC522 {
       ^~~~~~~
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:152:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MFRC522_I2C' to 'const MFRC522&'
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:152:7: note: candidate: 'constexpr MFRC522::MFRC522(MFRC522&&)'
.pio/libdeps/MyProject/MFRC522-spi-i2c-uart-async/src/MFRC522.h:152:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'MFRC522_I2C' to 'MFRC522&&'
```

Unfortunately there is no way to open an issue on the repository.
Why the official example does not work?

### UPDATE

Here the compatibility declaration for ESP32:

[image]

Comment: @VE7JRO they declare the compatibility for ESP32, see the picture in the question updated

Comment: @VE7JRO It returns: `error: cannot convert 'MFRC522_I2C' to 'MFRC522_I2C*' in initialization`

Comment: Guys, why the downvote? Without an explanation how can I improve my question? I did my homework: minimal and reproducible example, show effort to solve the issue by myself, complete output message. What else do you want?

Comment: you use a fork a of fork. the library is poorly maintained. use `MFRC522 mfrc522 = MFRC522(&dev);`

Answer (score -1):

if you look, it says, "Candidate expects 2 inputs, one provided."

so in the arduino IDE hover over the function and see what it expects.

(What your putting in `MFRC522(byte resetPowerDownPin);` what it expects: `MFRC522(byte resetPowerDownPin, Something else);`)

Comment: What it expects is in the declaration of the constructor: https://github.com/MakerSpaceLeiden/rfid/blob/master/src/MFRC522.cpp#L10. And is `MFRC522_BUS_DEVICE * dev`

Comment: I'm not putting any `byte`